# Angular constantly call function to update style

Tags: html, angular, svg

So I have this HTML:

```
<div cdkDrag>
    <div id="container">
        <div>
            <button id="add-left">+</button>
        </div>

        <div id="cell">
            <span class="cell-title">
                title
            </span>
            <span class="cell-desc">
                <p>desc</p>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button id="add-right" (click)="getPosition()">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div cdkDrag id="div2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:250px; left:600px; background:#4527a0; position:absolute;"></div>
<svg style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"><line id="line1" stroke="lime" style="stroke-width:3.5"/></svg>
```

And this Typescript function:

```
getPosition() {
    const line = document.getElementById('line1');
    const div1 = document.getElementById('add-right').getBoundingClientRect();
    const div2 = document.getElementById('div2').getBoundingClientRect();

    line.setAttribute('x1', (div1.left + div1.width / 2).toString());
    line.setAttribute('y1', (div1.top + div1.height / 2).toString());
    line.setAttribute('x2', (div2.left + div2.width / 2).toString());
    line.setAttribute('y2', (div2.top + div2.height / 2).toString());
}
```

The getPosition() function updates the svg lines coordinates to connect the box and the cell. The thing is, that I want to be able to move the cell and the box, and so the line along with it. How would I go about updating the line every time the boxes are moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [cdk docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag), there's a `cdkDragMoved` that is fired whenever the item is being dragged.

```html
<div cdkDrag (cdkDragMoved)="getPosition()">
    <div id="container">
        <div>
            <button id="add-left">+</button>
        </div>

        <div id="cell">
            <span class="cell-title">
                title
            </span>
            <span class="cell-desc">
                <p>desc</p>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button id="add-right" (click)="getPosition()">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The docs mention to use this with caution, but it seems to be fit for your use case.

> Emits as the user is dragging the item. Use with caution, because this event will fire for every pixel that the user has dragged.